# how to define pointer to templated function in header file in c++

Tags: c++, generics, using

I am not sure, this has been asked and already have answers,I could not get through it yet

```
       namespace mesh_planner
       {
       template<int Dim>
        class MeshPlanner {
        public:

            MeshPlanner();
            ~MeshPlanner();

            template<typename T>
            struct interpolation{
            T min_in, max_in, min_out, max_out;
            interpolation(){}
            interpolation(T min_in_, T max_in_, T min_out_, T max_out_): min_in(min_in_), max_in(max_in_), min_out(min_out_), max_out(max_out_){}

            };

            template<typename T, typename interpolate_type>
            T map_range_1d(T value, interpolate_type interp_type){
                double x = (value - interp_type.min_in) / (interp_type.max_in - interp_type.min_in);
                return interp_type.min_out + (interp_type.max_out - interp_type.min_out) * x;    
            }

            template<typename T, typename interpolate_type>
            std::pair<T,T> map_range_2d(T value_x, T value_y, interpolate_type interp_type_x, interpolate_type interp_type_y){
                std::pair<T,T> mapped_values = {map_range_1d(value_x, interp_type_x), map_range_1d(value_y, interp_type_y)}; 
                return mapped_values; 
            }

            typedef interpolation<double> interp1d;
            // constexpr auto map_range1d = &map_range_1d<double, interp1d>;
            
        };

        }
        typedef mesh_planner::MeshPlanner<2> MeshPlanner2D;
```

Now **I want to define pointer to the function** map_range_2d,

```
 constexpr auto map_range2d = &map_range_2d<double, interp1d>;
```

I can define this way, however, I need to define it in the header file without using `constexpr`

Could someone suggest me a proper way to do this?

Comment: Please don't spam with tags. Choose one C++ version or don't choose it at all. What does happen to constexpr if you remove it?

Comment: : error: non-static data member declared with placeholder ‘auto’

Comment: So, is it in a class? Please post a [mcve].

Comment: I can't find the location of `map_range2d` in the class.

Comment: its there, map_range_2d

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252072/discussion-between-gprathap-and-273k).

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with an emphasis on _minimal_.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't make the pointer a static member variable? You don't need it in every object instance.

```
static inline const auto* map_range1d = &map_range_1d<double, interp1d>;
```